# Is there a way to specify that the Dart formatter does not modify the source code but just format it?

Tags: optimization, formatting, dart, dart-editor

After applying the format operation on the source code the result source  not only getting formatted but it also modified (optimized?).

Before:

```dart
void main() {
  if(condition1) {
    // if condition 1
  } else if(condition2) {
    // if condition 2
  } else {
    // other case
  }
}

var condition1;
var condition2;
```

After:

```dart
void main() {
  if (condition1) {
    // if condition 1
  } else {
    if (condition2) {
      // if condition 2
    } else {
      // other case
    }
  }
}

var condition1;
var condition2;
```

**It does not suit me. This is my problem or is it possible to solve this?**

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that was fixed very recently.
- https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=17363  (should be fixed)
- https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16847  (similar bug - open)